# How to use SecureSWF obfuscation with an Adobe AIR file (Flash)

Tags: flash, air, obfuscation

I am trying to use the SecureSWF demo to package an Adobe AIR application in order to determine if we should buy the full version of SecureSWF for our project. The AIR file was created with the Flash CS5 authoring tool (not Flex).

However, I have not been able to find clear instructions on how to secure an AIR file using the software. I opened the installer (my_installer.air) in the program and it prompted me to find the adt.jar file; however, searching my system I found about 10 of these, relating to different Adobe programs. I chose the one associated with Flash CS5. I selected my certificate and signed it with the correct password. Right now I am just running in test mode to try to get a working file. However, after running secureSWF on the file, it will not install, giving the error "The application could not be installed because the AIR file is damaged. Try obtaining a new AIR file from the application author."

I have a feeling that this has something to do with either the adt.jar file or the certificate not being signed properly. But I have no idea what to do now and we really need to be able to obfuscate this project.

Has anyone used secureSWF with AIR before? Am I doing this wrong (i.e. should I be using the program with the project's swf file instead?) Please walk me through this as if I am 5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed it; I had specified the wrong certificate. Everything works like a charm now.